# Enterprise architect deletes foreign key when saving

Tags: enterprise-architect

When i do the CTRL+S combo to save my work, the foreign key that i have created dissapears and is missing when i reopen the file. Upon pressing CTRL+S the status line at the bottom says delete complete. I dont understand what its deleting when im asking it to save.

I have tried remaking it over 10 times now. Nothing seems to work, the data types are the same, databases have been selected. I dont know what else to try.

The way i generate the foreign keys.

Draw association from 1 to the other, foreign key dialog pops up, i check that the child and parent are correct, press OK.

Comment: Please state the EA release you use.

Comment: This sounds more like a bug or a usage issue than a "how-do-I-achieve-this" question. Have you tried asking Sparx support? They're usually pretty quick to respond.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I am using EA version 12.

Comment: @Uffe I thought maybe someone here has come across the problem and may know a solution, but i guess that may not be the case.

Comment: There are a couple of DB designers active on Sparx' forum. You might cross-post this. If you don't get a good answer you're better off taking Uffe's advice.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same issue. My workaround was not using the CTRL+S button. Instead just use the regular save button.

Answer (score 0):

While creating the foreign key relation change the index name to something else then the default, and try to save. This usually indicate the exact foreign key is in use

Answer (score 0):

This happened when I was connecting the foreign key for a child table that already had the column meant to be a foreign key. I deleted the column from that table and let the "Foreign Key Constraint" window create the column for me. It will create it for you if you have under a "Child: Table name", in a "Foreign Key Constraint" window a text "ForeignKey (*)".

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I shortened the constraint name first. Then all the constraints it generates will have shorter name. After saving and make sure the FK won't disappear. I restore the original table name at the end. It works for me.

Answer (score -1):

In case you save the object containing external references and open it in another EAP, which don't contain such object all the relations are not recovered. Couldn't this be your case?